# AbstractMethodError PushModuleReadyListener.ready

Tags: salesforce-sdk-android

I migrated sdk to 8.0.7 (compile sdk 31) and all works good if I launch my app in Android Studio: I see notifications, no any problems.

But the app which was built in Bitrise pipeline gets crashes. I could reproduce this crash creating an apk in Android Studio using gradle task `AssembleGmsDebug`.

I am not big expert in gradle, so I have no idea why this happens.
Here is crash report:

```
2022-11-02 18:43:46.700 16152-16152/cl.android.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cl.android.debug, PID: 16152
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.modules.push.PushModuleReadyListener.ready(com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.modules.ModuleInterface)"
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.modules.ModuleReadyHandler.execute(ModuleInterface.kt:28)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.modules.ModuleReadyHandler.deliverModule$lambda-0(ModuleInterface.kt:23)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.modules.ModuleReadyHandler.lambda$lmEjbogwdhDlXQhlK8RFw33EYss(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.modules.-$$Lambda$ModuleReadyHandler$lmEjbogwdhDlXQhlK8RFw33EYss.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Maybe somebody knows what is going wrong